# React Select is not keeping dropdown open in test but it is in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-select

I have this:

```
<AsyncReactSelect
    defaultOptions
    loadOptions={async () => [
      { value: "Pear", label: "Pear" },
      { value: "Banana", label: "Banana" },
      { value: "Raspberry", label: "Raspberry" },
    ]}
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    isMulti
  />
```

[image]

that works as I expect. i.e. Pear was selected and the dropdown remained opened

in my test I have

```
await act(async () => {
  // open the dropdown
  const selectDropdown = screen.getAllByRole("combobox")[0]
  await userEvent.click(selectDropdown)

  await screen.findByText("Pear")
  screen.debug() // first debug
  await userEvent.type(selectDropdown, "{enter}")

  screen.debug() // second debug
})
```

in the first debug, I clear see all the dropdown options in a list

but in the second one, I can never see them and I have no clue as to why. I have tried `fireEvent.click` too as I wasn't sure if something odd was happening in the click functions.

any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

I added in this and notice it's being called, it only gets called in the browser when I click outside the menu

```
 onMenuClose={() => {
          console.log("called the close!!")
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because of [this part](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/179#issuecomment-724273070) that this is happening.

Try this:

```
await act(async () => {
  // open the dropdown
  const selectDropdown = screen.getAllByRole("combobox")[0]
  await userEvent.click(selectDropdown)

  await screen.findByText("Pear")
  screen.debug() // first debug
  // await userEvent.type(selectDropdown, "{enter}")
  userEvent.keyboard("{enter}");

  screen.debug() // second debug
})
```

Further reading [here](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/179)

Comment: hmm, still doesn't seem to keep the dropdown open. appreciate the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

try this updated code

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
{ value: "1", label: "Test 1" },{ value: "2", label: "Test 2" },{ value: "3", label: "Test 3" },];


class App extends React.Component {
  state = { selectedOption: null};

handleChange = (selectedOption) => {

this.setState({ selectedOption }, () => console.log(`Option 
selected:`, this.state.selectedOption));
  };

render() {
const { selectedOption } = this.state;
 return <Select value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} options={options} />;
 }
}
```

actually, I want to ask you need to make your data structure like this data options array

also, you can see the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

Comment: can you explain how this would work? I can't see why it would. You are also not using the values I provided in the OQ

Comment: you can try this code in react component and only need one array that will pass in options you can set null in value for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).